# Addition of time with respect to current selected time period

Tags: php

I have an input field `purchase_date` in the format `dd-mm-yyyy` and the following select

```
<select name="warranty_period">
  <option selected="selected" value="30d">30 days</option>
  <option value="60d">60 days</option>
  <option value="90d">90 days</option>
  <option value="1y">1 year</option>
  <option value="2y">2 years</option>
  <option value="3y">3 years</option>
  <option value="5y">5 years</option>
  <option value="unlimited">Unlimited</option>
</select>
```

Now what I want to do is that I want to create a new variable `$expires_on` and its value should be `purchase_date + warranty_period`. 30d means 30 days, 60d means 60 days, 90d means 90 days and so on. How will I achieve that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
Please find the below solution

 $date = date("d-m-Y"); 
 list($day, $month, $year) = explode('-', $date); 
 $p_date = mktime(0, 0, 0, $month, $day, $year); //Purchase Date
echo "Purchase Date: ".date('d-m-Y',$p_date);
echo "</br>30 Days: ".$data = date('d-m-Y',strtotime(date("Y-m-d", $p_date) . " + 30 day")); 
echo "</br>60 Days: ".$data = date('d-m-Y',strtotime(date("Y-m-d", $p_date) . " + 60 day")); 
echo "</br>90 Days: ".$data = date('d-m-Y',strtotime(date("Y-m-d", $p_date) . " + 90 day")); 
echo "</br>1 Year:  ".$data = date('d-m-Y',strtotime(date("Y-m-d", $p_date) . " + 1 year")); 
echo "</br>2 Years: ".$data = date('d-m-Y',strtotime(date("Y-m-d", $p_date) . " + 2 year")); 
echo "</br>3 Years: ".$data = date('d-m-Y',strtotime(date("Y-m-d", $p_date) . " + 3 year")); 
echo "</br>5 Years: ".$data = date('d-m-Y',strtotime(date("Y-m-d", $p_date) . " + 5 year"));
```

Answer (score 1):

You can add inteval based on selected option from `select` tag.

Make sure you are using, [`(PHP 5 >= 5.3.0, PHP 7)`](http://php.net/manual/en/datetime.add.php)

```
$date = new DateTime('2000-01-01');
$interval = new DateInterval('P10D')   //add 10 days "PXD" x = no of days
$interval = new DateInterval('P1M');   //add 10 days "PXM" x = no of months
$date->add($interval);
echo $date->format('Y-m-d') . "\n";
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use PHP's [DateTime](http://php.net/manual/en/class.datetime.php) object for this:

```
$expires_on= DateTime::createFromFormat('d-m-Y', $purchase_date);
$expires_on->add(new DateInterval('P' . $warranty_period));
echo $expires_on->format('d-m-y');
```

Note, the "D", "M" or "Y" needs to be uppercase so either change the select options to "60D" (etc) use [strtoupper()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.strtoupper.php)):

```
$expires_on->add(new DateInterval('P' . strtoupper($warranty_period)));
```

Answer (score 0):

I found a working solution here. Here it is

```
$expires_on = '';
if ($data['expires_on']==''){
    if ($data['warranty_period']=='30d'){
        $expires_on = date('Y-m-d', strtotime($purchase_date. ' + 30 days'));
        } else if ($data['warranty_period']=='60d'){
        $expires_on = date('Y-m-d', strtotime($purchase_date. ' + 60 days'));
        } else if ($data['warranty_period']=='90d'){
        $expires_on = date('Y-m-d', strtotime($purchase_date. ' + 90 days'));
        } else if ($data['warranty_period']=='1y'){
        $expires_on = date('Y-m-d', strtotime($purchase_date. ' + 1 year'));
        } else if ($data['warranty_period']=='2y'){
        $expires_on = date('Y-m-d', strtotime($purchase_date. ' + 2 years'));
        } else if ($data['warranty_period']=='3y'){
        $expires_on = date('Y-m-d', strtotime($purchase_date. ' + 3 years'));
        } else if ($data['warranty_period']=='5y'){
        $expires_on = date('Y-m-d', strtotime($purchase_date. ' + 5 years'));
    }
```

}